Copy Raster from ESRI Living Atlas with Python
I am trying to use the ESRI Living Atlas "Terrain" raster layer as an input for the copy raster tool. I am able to perform this operation manually so have copied the "Copy Raster" portion of the code.  I am also able to access the Terrain layer alone so that portion appears to be correct.  When I combine the two, I am getting an error code.  This is my script thus far:
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.raster import ImageryLayer

# Connect to ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Enterprise
gis = GIS("https://www.arcgis.com","my_login" , "my_password")

# Access the Image Server and retrieve the elevation layer
server_url = "https://elevation.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/WorldElevation/Terrain/ImageServer"
terrain_layer = ImageryLayer(server_url, gis)

# Set the workspace to the geodatabase location
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Modeling_PythonTools.gdb"

# Define the input feature class
input_feature_class = "Model_2024"

# Define the output folder
output_folder = r"C:\Outputs"

try:
    with arcpy.EnvManager(outputCoordinateSystem='PROJCS["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",0.0],PARAMETER["Auxiliary_Sphere_Type",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]', snapRaster=terrain_layer, extent='-95.2058694319287 29.6965465890539 -95.1541935076243 29.7416535152976 GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]', cellSize=terrain_layer, cellAlignment="ALIGN_WITH_INPUT"):
        arcpy.management.CopyRaster(
            in_raster=terrain_layer,
            out_rasterdataset=r"C:\Test_v4.gdb\copy_raster",
            config_keyword="",
            background_value=None,
            nodata_value="",
            onebit_to_eightbit="NONE",
            colormap_to_RGB="NONE",
            pixel_type="32_BIT_FLOAT",
            scale_pixel_value="NONE",
            RGB_to_Colormap="NONE",
            format="GRID",
            transform="NONE",
            process_as_multidimensional="CURRENT_SLICE",
            build_multidimensional_transpose="NO_TRANSPOSE"
        )

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    # Get any messages from the last operation
    msgs = arcpy.GetMessages(2)
    print("ArcPy error:", msgs)
except Exception as e:
    print("Python error:", e)

  

The error code I am receiving is:
Python error: Object: Error in accessing environment <snapRaster>

Not entirely sure why this error is showing up.
